# OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 Mail keep quitting unexpectedly. This started happening after the last update

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I'm just wondering that why Mail keeps quitting after the 10.10.3 update.
The mail app worked fine and I never had to quit it, but now it happens occasionally.

Sorry I didn't provide those informations.
Here is the User Diagnostic Reports:

```
Crashed Thread:        18  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x7fbff45644a0 :: NSOperation 0x7fbff7e23ee0 (QOS: UTILITY)
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Thread 18 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x7fbff45644a0 :: NSOperation 0x7fbff7e23ee0 (QOS: UTILITY)
Thread 18 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
    0x7fff8d4d9000 -     0x7fff8d4e4ff7  com.apple.CrashReporterSupport (10.10 - 631) <D87A64FA-64B1-3B23-BB43-ADE173C108C6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/Versions/A/CrashReporterSupport
```

Let me know if I can provide more info to solve my question.

What I actually want to do is to make the mail app stable instead of crashing 2 or 3 times a day.

Comment: We could help you if you provide more info. Do you get any message when it quits? Could you open the Console log (located in your Utility folder) then copy some 30 lines before the time stamp. Time stamp is when it Quits (so take note of the time it happened).

Comment: One thing to do is check the diagnostic reports for the crashes. Open the Console app on your Mac, and open up the "User Diagnostic Reports" under "DIAGNOSTIC AND USAGE INFORMATION" in the sidebar panel. You should find crash reports for Mail there called things like "Mail_2015-04-160291449_name.crash". There is a lot of information there that might not be very clear but if you add it to your question it will help us give you a better answer.

Comment: Could you edit this to explain what you want as an end goal. Do you want troubleshooting info or advice how to delete that mail and set it up again? Do you want to know how to troubleshoot app crashes as opposed to just getting mail to work? What is the end goal so anyone hoping to answer knows what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of those repetitive crashes : a rule that tried moving email in a directory that does not exist anymore. Under 10.10.2 Mail would simply not do anything. Under 10.10.3 Mail 8.2 crashed and corrupt the mail index. Simply fixing the rules did solve my problem.

Comment: Sorry, it took me so long to see this message. Can you tell me how did you fix the rule?

Comment: In the end, I had to disable alll rules that where storing messages in directories located remotely (on Exchange).

Comment: I only got one rules which is "news from apple", but I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

another setting can bring relief:
Mail->Preferences->Accounts choose accounts one by one and in the "advanced" button uncheck "automatically detect and maintain account settings". Do the same for that account in the smtp settings.
Save.
Restart Mail.

Comment: Ok, I will try it asap. Will post afterwards.